# movable and resizable text edit control like in mspaint using wxpython

Tags: python, image-processing, wxpython, textinput

Hi I am trying to add some text to an image, and want adjust font, size, etc.
Is there any way to implement a mspaint style text input control in wxpython?
It have a rectangle area you can input text in it, and with 8 handler in 4 corner and 4 border to adjust size. I see many control like it in photoshop and other image process software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Whyteboard. I think it has one of those widgets and it's written in wxPython:

http://whyteboard.org/

Comment: Nah - I use a popup textctrl in a dialog. I've been meaning to create one for a while, just had a bit of difficulty and haven't got around to it. It's been about 5 months since I coded on it :-o